# What's the purpose of CookieSyncManager exactly?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm a bit confused about when and why to use CookieSyncManager. According to the docs, it can be used to manually force syncing the cookies stored in RAM to permanent storage. Can anyone describe a scenario in which this needs to be done?

In my application, I'm using CookieManager to extract cookies out of a WebView I show, after the user successfully logged in a webapp, using the WebView. Should I force a sync before trying to extract these cookies? So far, I was able to get the cookies without syncing, but reading about CookieSyncManager I'm starting to think that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You can see some examples of it [here](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/util/CookieStore.java) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/retain-android/source/browse/trunk/src/com/retain/AndroidHttpClient.java?spec=svn42&r=42)